# symfony2 is not a valid entity or mapped super class (used super class)

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

if i use

> use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

i get the following error

> Class \"SilexStarter\Entity\User\User\" sub class of \"SilexStarter\Entity\AbstractEntity\" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.

(without the use with alias it works fine).
The alias ist out of the [doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/annotations.html).

My user class: [user class](https://hastebin.com/wemikiqavo.php)
My AbstractEntity class: [AbstractEntity class](https://hastebin.com/ilufevabuk.php)

I already used google and stackoverflow (search), but i dont find any solution.
I hope you can help me ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the line

```
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="UserRepository")
```

to

```
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SilexStarter\Repository\UserRepository")
```

resolve the problem?

Comment: No, this is not the problem.
I only get the error if i use the alias for ORM (like the doctrine docu).